# Write data after fseek(), ftell() output is wrong, the data written before fseek() are all 0

Tags: c, fread, fseek

I first write 88, then use `fseek()` to position the file pointer to the beginning, and write 99, then position the file pointer to the end, use `ftell()` to view the size of the file (the target is sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) = 8), but got 4.
Finally, I tried to print out the two values I wrote (the target is 98, 88), but 99, 0 was output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("a", "wb");
    int a = 88;
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int c = 98;
    fwrite(&c, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("%d\n", ftell(fp));

    FILE* fpc = fopen("a", "rb");
    int b;
    fread(&b, sizeof(int), 1, fpc);
    int d;
    fread(&d, sizeof(int), 1, fpc);
    printf("%d, %d\n", b, d); // 98, 0
}
```

gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

Comment: You write 4 bytes so the size would be 4. You seek back to the beginning and overwrite the same 4 bytes, the file is still 4 bytes long. You should check the return value from `fread` to make sure it was successful before using the value you think you read.

Comment: Yes, the `int d` *happened* to already contain `0`. It could not be read from the file, which was only 4 bytes in size.

Comment: It looks like you trying to insert data at the beginning of the file while preserving and shifting forward existing data. You can't do that, files don't work this way.

Comment: Don't ignore the return values of the `fwrite` and `fread` calls.  If the `fread` return value is less than the third parameter (1 in this case), then it indicates the read failed.

Comment: Can you first move the file pointer to 4 and then jump to the beginning after writing, so as to avoid overwriting problems?